# Use specified quantifier in grep to retrieve satisfied vocabulary

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm trying to grab words from a file:

```
$ grep -o '\*\*[^*]*\*\*' Principles_20_LifePrinciples.md | grep -v -e "Origin" -e "Etymology"
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
**the state of feeling nervous or worried that sth bad is going to happen**
**a worry or fear about sth**
**a strong feeling of wanting to do sth or of wanting sth to happen**
```

The result I intend is to get only words:

```
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
```

Refactored code with specified quantifiers `{,20}`:

```
$ grep -E -o '\*\*[^*]{,20}\*\*' Principles_20_LifePrinciples.md
```

Unfortunately, it returns nothing.

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: The last `grep` command worked for me. Which version of Ubuntu are you using and what is the output of `grep --version`?

Comment: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD @muru

Comment: If you're not using Ubuntu, you should post the question on [unix.se] instead.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 @muru

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 has GNU grep 3.1. No Ubuntu has a BSD grep. How did you install BSD grep?

Comment: Sorry, AskDifferent is less dynamic as Ask ubuntu. Thank you very much @muru

Comment: [unix.se] is fairly active.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1019399/295286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that GNU grep supports `\w` for matching word characters (alphabets, digits and underscore), so you could easily match only word characters in the part between the asterisks:

```
grep -o '\*\*\w*\*\*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there with your first `grep` command.

If you only need to match line that have a single word, add a space in the `[^...]` regex:

```
$ grep -o '\*\*[^* ]*\*\*' file
**circumstance**
**case**
**condition**
**Anxiety**
**anxiety**
```